# BatchPool - AuthenticationErrorDetail The specified type of authentication SharedKey is not allowed when external resources of type Network are linked

Tags: azure-batch-account

Getting error while creating Azure Batch Pool with private network configuration.

```
BatchClient bClient = BatchClient.Open(new BatchSharedKeyCredentials(batchUri, accountName, accountKey));
PoolSpecification poolSp = new PoolSpecification();
poolSp.NetworkConfiguration = new NetworkConfiguration
                        {
                            SubnetId = "/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/{2}/virtualNetworks/{3}/subnets/{4}"
                        };
```

Getting errors when creating job

```
await job.CommitAsync();
```

Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Models.ErrorMessage - AuthenticationFailed
AuthenticationErrorDetail: The specified type of authentication SharedKey is not allowed when external resources of type Network are linked.

Answer (score 2):

After research, I found that it is mandatory to use AAD authentication when using VNET. The reason is when using a shared key, the key doesn't have permission to access Network resources.

You can read the article mentioned in [Authenticate Batch service solutions with Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth).